# WPF Evento OnLoad

Tags: c#, wpf, eventos

Estoy empezando a aprender C# con WPF y acabo de empezar con mi primer apalicación "útil", pero me encuentro con un pequeño bloqueo. Agradecería un poco de orientación para entender cómo resolverlo y si estoy haciendo algo mal.

Tengo la siguiente clase (recortada para quitar lo que no se usa ahora):

```
class SubjectManager
{
    private string filePath = "preguntas.txt";

    public List<ListBoxItem> SubjectList = new List<ListBoxItem>();

    public TextBlock ouputTextblock = new TextBlock();


    public void getSubjectList()
    {
        StreamReader sr;
        string line;

        sr = File.OpenText(filePath);
        addSystemMessage("El archivo " + filePath + " se ha abierto correctamente en modo lectura");
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            addNewSubject(getSubject(line));
        }
    }

    private void addSystemMessage(string message)
    {
        ouputTextblock.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("System: ")));
        ouputTextblock.Inlines.Add(new Run(message + "\n"));
    }
}
```

En la ventana tengo un Listbox y un TextBlock con lo siguientes eventos OnLoad:

```
private void ListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SubjectManager mySubjectmanager = new SubjectManager();
        mySubjectmanager.ouputTextblock = TextBlock_Messages;
        mySubjectmanager.getSubjectList();
        SubjectsListbox.ItemsSource = mySubjectmanager.SubjectList;
    }

private void TextBlock_Messages_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock_Messages.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

El objetivo era que cuando todo carga, el TextBlock se limpie con la instrucción TextBlock_Messages.Text = string.Empty y que posteriormente se vayan cargando los mensajes que vengan de la clase SubjectManager.

Pero el efecto que obtengo es el contrario, primero se cargan los mensajes y luego se limpia.

¿Hay alguna forma de ver/controlar el flujo de los eventos onLoad? Dicho de otro modo, forzar a que los controles se carguen en un orden deseado.

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo,

Comment: Si lo haces sobre el evento loaded del form vos controlas el orden de carga..

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias, no sabía que se podía hacer así.

Comment: Porfa, la respuesta, donde dice respuesta... auto responderte esta muy bien visto....

Answer (score 0):

**Posible solución:**

Pasarlo todo al evento Loaded de la window

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear textblock
        TextBlock_Messages.Text = string.Empty;

        // Create and fill subjectmanager
        SubjectManager subjectmanager = new SubjectManager();
        subjectmanager.ouputTextblock = TextBlock_Messages;
        subjectmanager.getSubjectList();
        SubjectsListbox.ItemsSource = subjectmanager.SubjectList;
    }
```